# React material UI icon insdie auto complete component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

All I want is to **put this target icon inside the autoComplete component**. I go through the documentation but could find a way.

In TextInput same thing can be achieved by doing this

```
<TextField
    className={classes.margin}
    id='input-with-icon-textfield'
    label='TextField'
    InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <AccountCircle />
            </InputAdornment>
        )
    }}
/>
```

How can I add that target icon inside the autoComplete component?
[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uicv4)

Any help!
Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Check out my answer of using `InputAdornment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working solution with material's way using `InputAdornment` at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ijzbt).

**Demo**

[image]

**Edit:**

Base on your new requirement we need to use style.

And I've also changed your label condition to:

```
label={inputValue ? "" : "Near Me..."}
```

New demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-j5yod?file=/demo.js).

**Result:**

[image]

**Latest:**

[image]

Comment: This is working fine. But I tiny change to code that I do not want "Add a location" label with border, instead I do want to show it inside the auto complete component unit user select a value. I've added  ```label={value ? "" : "Add a location"}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}`` these two line. Could you please send me how to add right margin to the icon in this case. New code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ogw1k

Comment: Check out the new link.

Comment: Can't we keep the target button to the left side and do this?

Comment: Why not? Check at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-j5yod?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

You could use style. Something like:

```
...
renderInput={(params) => (
 <div>
  <GpsFixedIcon className={classes.gpsIcon} /> //<-- style for icon
  <TextField
   {...params}
   label="Add a location"
   variant="outlined"
   fullWidth
  />
 </div>
)}
...
```

and in `useStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ...
  gpsIcon: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "3%"
  }
}));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pgd1m?file=/demo.js) your code modified.

Comment: This is messy. Because text will intersect with the icon.

Comment: Yes @ZunayedShahriar it is. Your answer is much better (even if in your solution the label is always on top like autocomplete is always focused).

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`InputAdornment` works with `Autocomplete`, you must pass the `InputProps` from Autocomplete to the `TextField`.

```
<Autocomplete
    renderInput={(params) =>
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label={'TextField'}
            InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AccountCircle />
                    </InputAdornment>
                ),
            }}
        />
    }
/>
```